# axios download every file with txt extension

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I try to download any file from server from the laravel  , but all files are downloaded as a .txt file

[image]
this is my javascript code :

```
        downloadAttachment:function (id){
        axios({
            url: '/api/user/downloadFile/'+id,
            method: 'GET',
            responseType: 'blob',
        }).then((response) => {
            let fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
            let fileLink = document.createElement('a');
            fileLink.href = fileURL;
            fileLink.setAttribute('download', response.data.type);
            document.body.appendChild(fileLink);
            fileLink.click();
        });
    }
```

Laravel :

```
    public function downloadDocument($file)
{
    $path=$file->src;
    if(Storage::exists($path))
    {
        $file=Storage::get($path);
        $type=Storage::mimeType($path);
        $response = Response::make($file, 200);
        $response->header("Content-Type", $type);
        return $response;
    }
    abort(404);
 }
```

Comment: Can you also show the browser console and network output for that download? The headers should be the only problem here if renaming `application_zip (1).txt` to `application.zip` is the correct file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Storage::download` instead:

```php
public function downloadDocument($file)
{
    $path = $file->src;

    if (Storage::exists($path)) {
        return Storage::download($path);
    }

    abort(404);
 }
```

Here is the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#downloading-files).

Answer (score 0):

Erm... Why waste time downloading it as a blob with axios and then save it? why not just do `fileLink.href = url` and download it directly without wasting any RAM?

Seems like everything you have to do is this:

```js
location = '/api/user/downloadFile/' + id
```

or this:

```html
<a href="/api/user/downloadFile/123">
```